# Future Value of Annuity Compounded Daily?

Tags: calculus, finance

(a) What is the future value of $4$ payments of $\$300$ made at the end of each year with interest rate being $11\%$ p.a. compounded daily?

I did $300  (1 + 0.11/365)^{365}\cdot 4  -1)/0.11/365  =  $550092.45$ which is wrong.

The options are

a. 1200.00
b. 4062.90
c. 1425.96
d. 918.43

(b) Obtas offers a mobile phone plan that charges $35 per month for 7 years. If you subscribe to this plan, calculate the present value of this plan, assuming you could have invested this money into a bank account that pays 6% p.a. payable annually.

a. 77329.59
b. 3621.34
c. 578.97
d. 2408.40

I have no idea how to start here.

Thank you so much.

Comment: (a) If you tried to calculate the formula exactly as you wrote it, it is not surprising that you got the wrong answer, because the formula does not make sense - the brackets do not match.  I'm not sure (because I don't understand financial calculations) but *possibly* this is your only mistake and if you fix it you will get the right answer.

Comment: (a) First of all, the value at *when* in the future? secondly, I think that they mean the 4 payments to be made once a year at the beginning of 4 years, not made all at once.

Comment: Not beginning of the year, *end*... "4 payments of $300 made at the end of each year".

Answer (score 1):

**(a)** Let $i^{(365)}=11\%$ the nominal interest rate compounded daily, so that the effective annual interest rate is $$i=\left(+1\frac{i^{(365)}}{365}\right)^{365}-1=11.63\%$$
and the future value $S$ of the periodic payment $P=300$ for $n=4$ years will be
$$
S=P\,s_{\overline{n}|i}=P\,\frac{(1+i)^n-1}{i}=1425.96
$$

**(b)** 
The effective interest rate is $i=6\%$, so you have that the monthly interest rate is 
$$
j=\frac{i^{(12)}}{12}=(1+i)^{1/12}-1=0.4868\%
$$
corrisponding to a nominal annual interest rate $i^{(12)}=5.84\%$ companndly monthly.

Thus the present value of the annuity immediate of payments $P=35$ for $n=12\times 7=84$ months is
$$
PV=P\,a_{\overline{n}|j}=P\,\frac{1-(1+j)^{-n}}{j}=2,408.40
$$

Answer (score 0):

**(a)**

1. Apart from proper placement of brackets, since the compounding is daily whereas the payment is annual, you first need to find the effective annual rate (APY), $[{(1+\frac{0.11}{365}})^{365} - 1]$
   which will obviously be higher than 0.11 (decimal fraction), say *r*
2. Then use $A  = \dfrac{300(({1+r})^4 - 1)}{r}$

By commonsense, if you do things rightly, you should get 1425.96

**(b)**

You should be knowing the formula to find the present value of a series of payments (PMT)

$PV = \dfrac{PMT[1-(1+r)^{-n}]}{r}$

The computations here are straightforward